# Read Command Line arguments and split and perform a loop and exlude the files

Tags: gradle

I want to send a command line arguments with comma separated, and In build.gradle I want to read the command line arguments, spilt them using a , separator and using a loop I want to exclude all the files specified from the command promt.

From the Command Prompt:

```sh
gradlew.bat -DccsspIgnoreTest=abcd,bdgc,cgfd \
            -DccsspTestVersion=01.19.00 \
            --continue test -b build.gradle
```

In build.gradle

```java
System.getProperty("ccsspIgnoreTest").split(',').each {
  def var = "**/"+it + "*"
  exclude 'var'
}
```

The exclude is not working here

I have tried to exclude outside the loop by manually specifying the file name, but I want to read the file from the command prompt.

exclude '**/abcd*'

The above code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [Gradle Test task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering) has built in capabilities filter tests. Furthermore there is no need to explicitly pass the build.gradle file to the [gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html). It will automatically use the build file in the same directory.

The `--tests` option can be used to select the tests to run. I recommend to filter those you want to run instead of those you want to ignore, because the latter is not possible with `--tests`. Let's say you want to run tests `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, then you can change your command line to

```
gradlew.bat --tests=foo,bar,baz \
            -DccsspTestVersion=01.19.00 \
            --continue test
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your suggestion,

In my project there are more than 300+ test cases, and when executing a project all the folders with test cases need to get executed and generate a report, so the best solution is to exclude the required test cases.

It has been resolved.
Instead of passing exclude 'var' , replace it with exclude var , as var is a variable and there is no need to put it in quotes.

Below is the solution for the same..

System.getProperty("ccsspIgnoreTest").split(',').each

{

def var = "**/"+it + "*"

exclude var

}

Thank you, Good Day

Shilpa